# 11.10 Server does not reconnect to network after router reboot (DHCP or Static IP)

Tags: 11.10, networking, server

If I reboot the router (Netgear DGN2200) my Ubuntu 11.10 Server box does not reconnect to the network. This is over a wired link either with a reserved IP Address over DHCP or a static IP Address configuration in /etc/network/interfaces as:

```
# The loopback network interface

   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface

   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.100
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.1.255
   network 192.168.1.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Both connection methods fail after a router reboot i.e. no ping, no ssh, no http. I have never had to do anything special to ensure reconnection before - but am I missing something?

Thanks

S

Comment: I have now tried this with two different NIC's and still get the same result, i.e. no reconnection on Router reboot. My testing strategy now is to try a direct wired connection (I am going through a junction box at the moment) and then swap out the router for another. If still no luck I guess this may be something deeper. Again if anyone has any ideas let m eknow.

Answer (score 1):

you could try adding the following before auto eth0 line in the interfaces file;

allow-hotplug eth0

this should start the interface eth0 when th kernel detects a hotplug event from teh interface.

ifdown eth0 #this drops the eth0 interface NB: if SSH'd etc.. it will kill your connection
ifup eth0 # brings the connection back..

i'd set a continous ping from another machine to the server... bounce the router and see what happens.  you many need to restart the server for the "allow...." line to take affect.  I think the ifup\down does it too.. its been a while.